# Javascript mouseover event delegation

Tags: javascript

I have the following code.
How can I affect the status of other links when the cursor is on a link?
For example I would like that when the mouse is over a link I can affect the opacity of the other links.
I thought of a way to add the event to the link parent nav links and then check if the event is really on the link or outside.

Is the method I started good or I should approach event delegation

```js
const nav = document.querySelector(".nav__links");
const item = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll(".nav__item"));
const link = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll(".nav__link"));

link.forEach(t => t.addEventListener('mouseover' ,function(e){
const targetLink = e.target ;
console.log(targetLink) ;

if ( t !==targetLink) {
  t.style.opacity = 0.2;
}
})) ;
```

```css
.nav__links {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content:center;
  }
  
.nav__item {
  margin-left: 0.7rem;
}
```

```html
 <ul class="nav__links">
          <li class="nav__item">
            <a class="nav__link" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav__item">
            <a class="nav__link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav__item">
            <a class="nav__link" href="#">Testimonials</a>
          </li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're okay with dimming the options when the mouse is over the nav list and then not dimming the active one, you can do this just with CSS (I added a bit of transition to it, but you can remove that):

```css
.nav__links:hover li {
    opacity: 0.2;
    transition: opacity 0.1s;
}
.nav__links:hover li:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Live Example:

```css
.nav__links {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
    justify-content: center;
}
.nav__links:hover li {
    opacity: 0.2;
    transition: opacity 0.1s;
}
.nav__links:hover li:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.nav__item {
  margin-left: 0.7rem;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav__links">
  <li class="nav__item">
    <a class="nav__link" href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav__item">
    <a class="nav__link" href="#">About</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav__item">
    <a class="nav__link" href="#">Testimonials</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

That also has the advantage that there's no flashing as you move the mouse across from one nav item to the next (going out of one `li`, over the `ul`, then into the next `li`).

But if you only want them dimmed when one of the nav items is hovered, I don't think we can do it just with CSS because there's no general sibling combinator (there's just the *next* sibling [`+`] or *subsequent* sibling [`~`]).

But we can let CSS do most of the work. The trick is making sure that we un-dim things when the mouse is no longer over any of the nav items. Remember that the mouse can jump out of elements (for instance, if the user <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd>s to a different app, moves the mouse, and then tabs back to the page), so we have to be fairly aggressive about un-dimming things.

Here's a version that uses a passive `mousemove` handler on the `document`. Normally I'd avoid a `mousemove` handler on `document` since it will get fired a **lot**, but what we're doing inside the handler is really quick:

```js
document.addEventListener("mouseover", event => {
    const li = event.target.closest(".nav__links li");
    if (li) {
        nav.classList.add("dimmed");
    } else {
        nav.classList.remove("dimmed");
    }
}, {passive: true});
```

Then we throw some CSS at it:

```css
.nav__links.dimmed li {
    opacity: 0.2;
    transition: opacity 0.1s;
}
.nav__links.dimmed li:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const nav = document.querySelector(".nav__links");

document.addEventListener("mouseover", event => {
    const li = event.target.closest(".nav__links li");
    if (li) {
        nav.classList.add("dimmed");
    } else {
        nav.classList.remove("dimmed");
    }
}, {passive: true});
```

```css
.nav__links {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
    justify-content: center;
}
.nav__links.dimmed li {
    opacity: 0.2;
    transition: opacity 0.1s;
}
.nav__links.dimmed li:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.nav__item {
  margin-left: 0.7rem;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav__links">
  <li class="nav__item">
    <a class="nav__link" href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav__item">
    <a class="nav__link" href="#">About</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav__item">
    <a class="nav__link" href="#">Testimonials</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```